# C++ enum equivalent - convert to constant expression

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

Based on this question:

["enum class" emulation or solid alternative for MSVC 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980280/enum-class-emulation-or-solid-alternative-for-msvc-10-0)

I would like to ask a couple of things. Assuming this code:

```
struct DeletionMode_E
{
    static DeletionMode_E const Off;
    static DeletionMode_E const DirSize;
    static DeletionMode_E const FileNumberSize;
    static DeletionMode_E const DirAndFileNumberSize;

    operator int const() const { return myVal; }

private:
    explicit DeletionMode_E(const int & v) : myVal(v) { }
    const int myVal;
};
```

And their subsequent definitions :

```
    Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E const Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E::Off(0);
    Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E const Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E::DirSize(1);
    Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E const Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E::FileNumberSize(2);
    Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E const Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E::DirAndFileNumberSize(3);
```

One can use this like :

```
    void Log4Reconstruction::setDeletionMode( Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E const & delMode_in)
    {
        std::cout << delMode_in << std::endl;

        switch(delMode_in)
        {
        //case Log4Reconstruction::DeletionMode_E::Off: C2051 case expression not constant
        //  std::cout << "Off" << std::endl;
        //  break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "File number" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Why is the function call operator called? How would one call it manually in order to solve the "problem" in the case statement? I am using MSVS 2008 **no** external libs are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function-call operator declared here.

```
operator int const() const { return myVal; }
```

Is a user-defined conversion which converts an object of type `DeletionMode_E` to a constant integer. To invoke it, you have to perform a cast (this is done implicitly in your `switch`-statement).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to "somehow" use this conversion also to the case?

Comment: @FailedDev: Not with C++03. As @Potatoswatter explains in his answer, C++11 has the `constexpr`-keyword for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I will stick to using ints for now and update this when we move to C++11.

Answer (score 2):

In C++03, a function call cannot occur in a constant expression (such as a case label), so it's a no-go. In C++11, you would simply have to mark the conversion function and constructor as `constexpr`.

I'm not sure what you mean by "function call operator." If you mean the function `operator int const()` (the conversion function), it is called because the `switch` statement expects an integral expression, so the conversion function is used to perform the conversion — that's what they do. Incidentally, the first `const` is useless and it should be `operator int() const { return myVal; }`. To call it manually, just use its name in the usual syntax: `delMode_in.operator int const()`.

The `_E` suffix seems to indicate emulation of some aspects of enumerations. Why not just use an `enum`?

Comment: I think the OP wants to emulate some of the functionality of Java-Enums, hence the complex construct.