# C++11 Polyfills

Tags: c++, c++11, feature-detection, waf

I am starting a new project that will be targeting `MSVC`, `GCC (latest)`, `GCC 4.3 ARM` and more.  The `waf` build system we have built has `C++11` feature detection of the compiler.

I now have preprocessor macros for all features in compiler that I am targeting for `C++11`, for example `#ifdef WAF_FEATURE_CXX_STRONGLY_TYPED_ENUMS`.  I can therefore compile different code for what the compiler supports. As `GCC` nearly supports it all be `MSVC` isn't even close (even with `MSVC` 11)

This got me thinking about web development polyfills - if the feature isn't available implement it with the feature set available.

This is no way near as simple as web development polyfills as for `C++11` but is there anything that I can simply implement with C++03 if the compiler doesn't support it?

This boils down to the fact that I want to use strongly typed enumerators in my public API but the scoping `MyClass::MyEnumerator::EnumValue` will look more like `MyClass::EnumValue` in `C++03`.  Is there anyway I can get the same to occur in `C++03` easily:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
#ifdef WAF_FEATURE_CXX_STRONGLY_TYPED_ENUMS
        enum class MyEnumerator : unsigned int {
#else
        enum MyEnumerator {
#endif
             EnumValue = 0
        }
    void method(MyEnumerator e);
}

MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.method(MyClass::MyEnumerator::EnumValue) // C++11
mc.method(MyClass::EnumValue)               // C++03 :(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you'll need to do (I made other trivial fixes about pointers and non-pointer access).
Bsically, it's what @demi said.  I had to make a dummy enum name.  This works in g++-4.7.

```
class MyClass {
    public:
#if __cplusplus > 201000
        enum class MyEnumerator : unsigned int {
             EnumValue = 0
        };
    void method(MyEnumerator e) {}
#else
        class MyEnumerator {
        public:
          enum Dummy {
             EnumValue = 0
          };
        };
    void method(MyEnumerator::Dummy e) {}
#endif
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;
    mc.method(MyClass::MyEnumerator::EnumValue); // C++11 or C++03
}
```

Comment: That is what I've ended up with - the method parameter declaration needs to have the dummy enum

Answer (score 1):

You may emulate `enum class` as class. Your boilerplate code will be only in definition, but usage will be same for C++11 and C++03, and may be done with templates/macros. [Look answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980280/enum-class-emulation-or-solid-alternative-for-msvc-10-0)