# Is it safe to disable MSVC warning C4482?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010

While qualifying an enumeration value with the name of the enumeration is not valid C++03, it is valid C++11, from what I understand. Despite this, MSVC 10 generates warning C4482 for the following:

```
enum E { A, B };

int i = E::A;  // warning C4482 (but valid C++11?)
```

Since much of our code uses C++11 features (especially lambdas), it seems safe to disable this warning. Am I right that the code is valid C++11?

Note: I did not write the code in question, and I would prefer to not go through and change every occurrence of this.

**Edit:** Added some relevant links.

- [MSDN page for the warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173704(v=VS.100).aspx).
- [Another question about the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/514194/320418). The question and answers all seem to reference C++03.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since much of our code uses C++11 features (especially lambdas), it seems safe to disable this warning.

If you're already relying on C++11 features, then yes. C++11 does allow you to use regular enums scoped by the enumeration's name. Microsoft had this as an extension for some time, so they issued a warning about the non-standard behavior.

So you can disable it.

Note that older compilers like VC2010, instead of warning, did raise compile error `C2653` (with message "... is not a class or namespace name").

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had thought. I needed someone to verify that I wasn't missing something.